# How to optimally distinguish between linearly independent vectors in higher dimensional complex/real space?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, qa.quantum-algebra

I have to distinguish between 4 linearly independent vectors belonging to $\mathbb{C^{16}}$ space by creating a set of *Positive Operator Valued Measurements (POVM)* that will act on these vectors. I have found that the given set of vectors are such that there exists no projectors which can categorize them into mutually orthogonal sub-spaces under $\mathbb{C^{16}}$, so that I cannot simplify the problem as a problem in two vectors within these subspaces. The set of POVM ${\{E_i\}}$ has to follow completeness $\sum{_{i=1}^n E_i=\mathbb{I}}$ for some $n$ and optimally distinguish between these vectors with maximum probability possible through optimization. I tried generalizing the procedure proposed in http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/31/34/013/pdf for 4 vectors in $\mathbb{R^4}$ but it is not working out because of the fact that the cross product they used in 3 dimensions cannot be generalized in 4 or higher dimensions directly (Hurwitz Theorem, composition algebra). On page 5 of the paper they have proposed to use outer product for its generalization, but that is not satisfying the matrix multiplication. If someone may help doing the same procedure in $\mathbb{R^4}$ for four vectors, would be enough help I seek for its use in $\mathbb{C^{16}}$ space.

Comment: Please make precise what you mean by *distinguish*; it would also be helpful if you gave an example.

Comment: By distinguishing I mean applying the operators to these 4 vectors gives me one of them uniquely and makes the other vanish or at least gives a linear combination of the 4 with very high probability of one and vanishingly of the other ones (this is optimization distinguishability) when they are not orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

Let the independent 4 vectors be $(v_1,...,v_4)$.

For each $1\leq i\leq 4$ let $\phi_i$ be in the span of the four, but orthogonal to $v_i$ (achieved e.g. by Gram-Schmidt). Then $E_i=|\phi_i\rangle\langle\phi_i|$ distinguishes the $i$'th vector, and you may complement by a projection $E_0$ onto the orthogonal complement of the 4 vectors if you want a full decomposition.

Is this sort of in the right direction for you?

Comment: Yes, mathematically that will work, but how do I guarantee the maximization the probability of distinction through that?

Comment: Let $\{\rho_i,1\leq i\leq m\}$ be a set of linearly independent density operators
$\rho_i$ with prior probabilities $p_i$. Then the optimal measurement
is a von Neumann measurement with measurement operators
$\{\Pi_i=\mathcal{P}_{\mathcal{S_i}},1\leq i\leq m\}$ where $\mathcal{P}_{\mathcal{S_i}}$ is an orthogonal projection
onto an $r_i$-dimensional subspace $\mathcal{S_i}$ of $\mathcal{H}$ (*Hilbert space* of $\rho_i$'s) with $r_i=
rank(\rho_i)$ and $\mathcal{P}_{\mathcal{S_i}}\mathcal{P}_{\mathcal{S_j}}=\delta^i_j\mathcal{P}_{\mathcal{S_i}}$ (orthonormality of operators).

Comment: This is a theorem I found which says something similar, but how do I construct the $\mathcal{P}_{\mathcal{S_i}}$ for each $\rho_i$?

Comment: @SiddhāntSingh  By linearly independent do you mean as operators in $H$? Your density operators, do they take the form of a finite sum: $\sum_j \lambda_j  |\phi_j\rangle\langle \phi_j|$, $\lambda_j>0$? And the ranges of different $\rho_i$'s may have non-empty intersections, or perhaps this would be inconsistent with your orthonormality of operators (usually not asked for in POVM as far as I know)

Comment: Yes, they take that form with different eigenvectors but some degenerate eigenvalues $\lambda_j$'s for each $\rho_i$ eigen expansion. But the 4 matrices I have, do not have all orthogonal subspaces (there are intersecting subspaces), hence I need an optimization to operate over them to achieve distinction with maximum probability. 
How to construct the $\phi_i$ that you initially pointed out?

Comment: For $\phi_1$, I would take Gram-Schmidt orthonormalise $v_2,v_3,v_4,v_1$ (in that order)  to obtain an orthonormal base $e_2,e_3,e_4,\phi_1$, then $\phi_1$ has a non-zero projection on $v_1$ and is orthogonal to each of $v_2,v_3,v_4$. Then repeat and orthonormalize $v_1,v_3,v_4,v_2$ (in that order) to get $e_1,e_3,e_4,\phi_2$, etc...  Would the $\phi_i$'s have the desired properties?

Comment: Thank you for your response H.H. Rugh! However, I am forbidden to use any orthogonalization method such as Gram-Schmidt, because here the vectors are physically "Quantum States" which cannot be disturbed and turned into Orthogonal vectors. Perhaps, I found one solution to the problem by proposing a set of POVM here, but the upper bound on the probability of distinctions isn't proved. For these vectors, only a POVM can be applied which corresponds to a measurement device for a quantum state (these 4 vectors in the Hilbert Space). So, still a general solution to my problem is unknown.